# What is difference between core view and template views in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am little bit confused about normal view and MVC view. What is the difference between both view and why we use blade in framework?

Comment: I'd recommend to add links/other context to the terms usage. Your question entitled with PHP, but "core view" and "template view" sounds like you're actually asking about MVC (moreover, a specific implementation of MVC). Perhaps you should change the title with "in Laravel".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blade is a templating engine. That means it has some special features that are helpful to you as a developer, such as easily extending other templates or handling php loops in a clean, readable way. You can find an excellent summary of them in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade

Blade files typically end in `.blade.php` but there's nothing that says you can't use regular `.php` files - or another templating engine, if you pull it in through composer. Like most features of Laravel, Blade is entirely optional. But of course: if you don't use Blade, you won't get the features of Blade.

A view in Laravel terms is simply a named template file, Blade or not. You can, for instance, use the `view()` shortcut function to generate a response to send back to the user, from any template file in your application.